# Rich Text Field not visible in aspx page sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have added a SharePoint:RichTextField  in my aspx page main content as follows. But when I open the page the Rich text box is not visible.
I am not sure why this is happening. I am testing it in IE and Chrome.

```
            <asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
                <asp:Panel ID="panel2" runat="server">
                      <SharePoint:RichTextField ControlMode="Display" HandleTextField="true" Visible="true"  runat="server"   id="RichTextFieldnew"></SharePoint:RichTextField>

               <%--  <uc:RichText runat="server" />--%>
                    </asp:Panel>
            </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code 
`<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox runat="server" ID="idRichTxtBox" Rows="10" RichText="true" TextMode="MultiLine" RichTextMode="FullHtml" AllowHyperlink="true" ></SharePoint:InputFormTextBox>`

Comment: I have tried to use that at first but it had issues with Firefox and Chrome but it worked in IE. So I wanted to try RichTextField and see how that behaves why is that not shown to my page is the question.